# Difficult proof about coprime and factors of numbers!

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am attempting a proof but it is driving me insane as I cannot see what I should do.

Given that $a$ is coprime to be $b$ and that $a|c$ and $b|c$ prove $ab|c$.

I simply wrote down what I know and tried to see what I could but but it made no difference and I still don't see how to proceed.

$a$ is coprime to be $b$ $\implies 1=ax+by$

$a|c \implies c=an$

$b|c \implies c=bm$

and I want to show

$ab|c \implies c=(ab)k$

but I'm so stuck.

Any help please?

**Got it thanks!**

Comment: @Sal, I should go to sleep. *facepalm*

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean, prove $ab|c^2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using your notation,
$$\begin{align*}
1 & =ax+by\\
c&=cax+cby\\
c&=(bm)ax+(an)by\\
c&=(ab)(mx+ny)
\end{align*}$$
Therefore $ab\mid c$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Think about the problem in terms of prime factorizations.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\,\ a,b\mid c\iff ab\mid ac,bc\iff ab\mid (ac,bc)=(a,b)c=c$